# Access to certain fields on put/get methods in WCF Data Service

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, permissions, wcf-data-services

At first technologies which I'm using:

- Data model: Entity framework
- Service: WCF Data Service

I've just wrote WCF Data Service application. I added custom authentication/authorization actions to provide some restrictions to prevent removing, updating and etc. access for every users.

It's working fine, but right now I have a new problem.

User who can edit User_table he can also remove IsBanned flag from his account or change his role...
For example I have following entity model:

```
User_table
-----------
id
user_id
name
is_banned
role
```

My implementation of access roles is in **ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest** where i'm parsing the httpContext where i'm looking for the http method and table name.

To filter the data which is returned to user, I'm using Interceptors. For instance my query interceptor looks as follows:

```
    [QueryInterceptor("User_table")]
    public Expression<Func<User_table, bool>> OnTagt() {
        MyPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User as MyPrincipal;
        if( user.IsInRole("NormalUser") )
            return o => o.user_id == user.id;
        else
            throw new DataServiceException("You must be logged in");
    }
```

Of course i'm using some of columns which I don't want to show to user in my authentication/authorization methods so I don't want to remove it from Data Model.

In addition depending on which role the user belongs to, he will see different columns.

The simplest solution which comes to my mind is to create separate data models for every roles. It could be very terrible and problematic.

I don't want to user views because of their low level support in EF.

I found only a few posts here related to my problem but unfortunately it was not solved my problem.

Do you have any suggestion, or solutions of this problem?

Comment: WCF data services are not suitable technology for situation where you need data driven security. As you have already found different set of columns per role means different "entity". Different update permissions will most probably lead to different entity as well but in the same time EF will not allow you having single table mapped to multiple entities. You need some intermediate abstraction and it leads you outside of WCF Data Services scope towards WCF + EF or ASP.NET WEB API + EF.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka if we are ruling out (WCF/Web API) + EF for slightly security trimmed services what else can we use then ?